# Remove all lines containing two times a character

Tags: notepad++

I have 200+ lines in Notepad++ and I's like to mark all lines that contains two times the character ".", point.

For example :

```
test.com
test.co.uk [MARK]
test.net
```

Thanks.

Comment: Notepad++ supports regular expressions, so this should be pretty simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression pattern: `^.*\..*\..*$`

[image: Find the line that contains dot character 2 times]

Comment: This works, but make sure the checkbox `. matches newline` is not checked

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

- Find what: `^(?:[^.\r\n]*\.){2,}.*$`

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of line
  (?:           : start non capture group
    [^.\r\n]*   : 0 or more any character that is not a dot or a linebreak
    \.          : a dot
  ){2,}         : end group, must appear at least twice
  .*            : 0 or more any character
$               : end of line
```

Comment: This would not find a match if the line was the last line and not followed by a newline.

Comment: @Pharaoh: True, fixed.